# How to show distance from user location to destination?

Tags: magento2.3, google-map

We have a pickup address and google API key. We want to show the approximate location from the user to the destination (pickup address).

How can I do that?

Looking for help!

Answer (score 1):

- You may explore these settings under
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix
- You can create custom module to get the location distance against two(pickup and user) address by using above API

Comment: How can I use this API in custom module?